# Inline block elements break at different screen widths based on the content of the page

Tags: html, css

So I have two pages, one with a `div` containing a header and a paragraph, and one with a div containing multiple `div`s that float left.
At the top of both of these pages I have this bit:

```
<div class="head">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="meniu">
                    <a href="index.html">
                         <div class="button">Acasa</div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="about.html">
                         <div class="button">Despre</div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="">
                         <div class="button">Contact</div>
                    </a>
                    <a href="">
                         <div class="button">Produse</div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="prod">
                                <a href="">
                                     <div class="button">Genti</div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="">
                                     <div class="button">Pantofi</div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="rochii.html">
                                     <div class="button">Rochii</div>
                                </a>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I have this in the css file:

```
.button{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 50px;
}
```

And the buttons appear one next to each other.
When I shrink the window down to a certain value, the last button goes below the other lines.
My problem is, on the first page this happens at one width, and on the second page, it happens at a different width. Any idea why that is?

Here is a code snippet:

```css
    .button{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 20px 50px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="head">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="meniu">
                        <a href="index.html">
                             <div class="button">Acasa</div>
                        </a>
                        <a href="about.html">
                             <div class="button">Despre</div>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                             <div class="button">Contact</div>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                             <div class="button">Produse</div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="prod">
                                    <a href="">
                                         <div class="button">Genti</div>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="">
                                         <div class="button">Pantofi</div>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="rochii.html">
                                         <div class="button">Rochii</div>
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Does the buttons have the same text in each pages? Is there anything different on one of the pages (in the same element containing the buttons)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I leave an upvote to your post. I hope it motivates you to keep going.